# I get a vibration in steering wheel at highway speed and a knock or clanking noise at slow speeds

Tags: suspension

I have just had new tires put on and have checked the balance twice and also replaced the lower ball joint and had the new tires aligned. Vibration has become very noticeable. There's no play in the steering and don't get that clicking noise with a bad tie rod. Is it a strut even if there's no bounce?

Answer (score 2):

Does it click when you turn? Assuming this is a front wheel drive car, it sounds like it is possibly a CV joint going bad.